# FileSystemWatcher to watch UNC path

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

There are no shortage of questions on this topic, but I'm still having trouble. Here is my situation. I've got a service that I need to watch a path that is specified in the config file. It works great when I used a local drive.

However, when I change it to something like `\\server2\secondary\temp\watch_folder` the service does not start. The error in the log is

> The directory name \\server2\secondary\temp\watch_folder is invalid.

If I copy that directly into Windows Explorer the folder opens fine. If I take my code and paste it into an old Winforms app it works fine. I've tried all of the "Log On As" accounts. I set it to use the Administrator account, but still no dice.

Here is my code:

```
_watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
_watcher.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WatchFolder"];
_watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
_watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
_watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
_watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);
_watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Any ideas? I'm at a loss and at this point I think I've been staring at it too long. I sincerely appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Nick

***EDIT***
Here is the exception:

> Service cannot be started. System.ArgumentException: The directory name \server2\Secondary\temp\watch_folder is invalid.
>      at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_Path(String value)
>      at FileWatcher.FileWatcher.Watch()
>      at FileWatcher.FileWatcher.OnStart(String[] args)
>      at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)

Comment: Do you mean the problem has been solved?

Comment: No, the problem has not been solved. I'm still unable to start the service.

Comment: Do you get any exception errors? Do you know how to debug a Windows Service? Any info on the errors helps.

Comment: I suspect there is something unique about directory \\server2\...watch_folder since other directories work, as you said. Review the read/write permissions for example.

Comment: Is the server you are wanting to watch running Windows?

Comment: server2 is running Windows Server 2003. Ok, I pointed the service to an old Vista machine and it worked. I'm not sure what the issue is with the other server, but at least I know my code should be good. I'll figure out the permissions issue now. I really appreciate all of your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileSystemWatcher Fails to access network drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960318/filesystemwatcher-fails-to-access-network-drive)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just tried this:

```
var _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
_watcher.Path = @"\\10.31.2.221\shared\";
_watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
_watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
_watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler((x, y) =>Console.WriteLine("Created"));
_watcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler( (x, y) =>Console.WriteLine("Error"));
_watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
Console.ReadKey();
```

That works without problems, however i replicated your exception just when:

- The running user doesn't have permissions to read the remote folder.
- The remote folder doesn't exist.

Your problem surely is related with permissions, I think that the running user doesn't have the permissions needed.

Another thing that you can try is map the remote folder to one local.

Execute this in the cmd:

```
NET USE Z: \\server2\Secondary\temp\watch_folder /user:Domain\UserName Password
```

Then in your code:

```
_watcher.Path = @"Z:\";
```

Comment: I had this issue and it was a permission issue on the folder. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had this problem too. My service with a FileSystemWatcher was set up to monitor a folder on a network drive as NetworkService, **and the path has spaces in it so I thought that was the problem.** I was running it on my laptop. After reading your answer about the permissions, I installed the service with the FileSystemWatcher on the app server, and the problem disappeared! The service has the right permissions under NetworkService when running from that app server. - Helpful answer!

Comment: @marco medrano c:\windows\system32\foldername this is on local system and it returns directory name doesn't exist , its working from visual studio but gives exception from a windows service.any idea?

Comment: @Dragon I think you might be using a relative path rather than the absolute path (if it does work in VS)

Answer (score 7):

Your service is probably running under a user account that does not have permission to that share.  Try changing the windows service to run under different credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I found a really cool way to get UNC with credentials working with FileSystemWatcher in a windows service on codeproject.

see Adrian Hayes post: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43091/Connect-to-a-UNC-Path-with-Credentials

His solution works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem. My fix was to include our company's domain name in the server path:

```
\\servername.company.com\directorytowatch
```

Comment: If you are using a windows service the log on user must be a domain user.

Answer (score -1):

You may need to have your path as the below:

```
\\\\server2\\Secondary\\temp\\watch_folder
```

or

```
@"\\server2\Secondary\temp\watch_folder"
```

Comment: You need more than two slashes in front of server2 to do it that way: Try     \\\\server2\\Secondary\\temp\\watch_folder

Comment: @JamesBellaby Rather than correct a wrong answer, I suggest writing your own instead.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Reasons to why it is wrong? You should elaborate more on why you think things are wrong in order to provide better direction for people reading the comments of a perceived incorrect answer...

Comment: @JamesBellaby **You** suggested a correction to this answer, I assume you know what was wrong with the answer.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I corrected a typo. You're assuming it's incorrect.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I'll not help in future to correct wrong answers and continue to bloat the answer sections. Or not do it in future at all to avoid the highly criticising community of StackOverflow. FYI does the answer look incorrect after I edited it? If not what is the problem?

Comment: @JamesBellaby Well my opinion was clearly overruled by the other reviewers, who felt that your edit was valuable. For the record, I merely felt that it would have been more valuable as its own answer (because that associates the answer with *you* and gives you reputation when people upvote it), and that this answer, as it previously was, wasn’t helpful and could have been deleted instead.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph OK but according to the dates it obviously wasn't going to get deleted any time soon. I won't help out next time. FYI i couldn't care less about the points system. It obviously clouds peoples judgments.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph I personally hate this reputation system of Stack overflow. For this very reason. I don't wont points I want correct information.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph You also need to rethink how you write comments. You came across as annoyed that I didn't do what you want.

Comment: @JamesBellaby Comments are meant for *concise* communication. If you read annoyance into my comment that’s on you. By contrast, I can tell you, outright, that I am by now annoyed.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph "Rather than correct a wrong answer, I suggest writing your own instead" vs "I think you would benefit from making this your own answer" That is about the same (concise), more polite and starts off being an opinion by mentioning that you think... etc.