# FileSystemWatcher rename Event not firing for subdirectory network path. Except for OnCreated event. It is working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

- My requirement

I am creating one desktop application , I need a network path file information which  raname and  create ,for that I use FileSystemWatcher
it's  provide Created,Renamed,changes and deleted event

- My problem

FileSystemWatcher  rename event not firing for subdirectory network path,
I already  set `watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true`, but it not work for rename

```
public void Setup() {

    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher{
        Path = "My network path",
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Security, Filter = "*"
    };

    watcher.Created += OnCreated;
    watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
    // uncomment out line below to add the error handler 
    watcher.Error += OnError; 
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

public static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{           
    try
    {                       
        MessageBox.Show("Raname call");
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        errorLog(Ex);
    }
}           

public static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OnCreated call");
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
         errorLog(Ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Other people have had similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219373/filesystemwatcher-to-watch-unc-path, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960318/filesystemwatcher-fails-to-access-network-drive. Do either of these apply to you?

Comment: Do not use MessageBox in events, specially filesystemwatchers, I would recommend plain Console.WriteLine("bla bla").