# Can't catch network file change

Tags: c#, .net

I use below c# code to catch all chnges in file system (like file rename or creat etc.) and it works great. But when i change path from "D:\" to "\\ServerName\folder" - program stop working. But in MSDN FileSystemWatcher class description sad: "...You can create a component to watch files on a local computer, a **network drive**, or a **remote computer**..."
Could you help me emprove my code to work with network folders plz.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace consoleWatcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher myWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher("D:\\");
            myWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite  | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            myWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            myWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            myWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            myWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

            myWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            myWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.Read();

        }

        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.

            Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        }

        private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.

            Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/eventsanddelegates/article.php/c9113/FileSystemWatchermdashWhy-Does-It-Stop-Working.htm ?

Comment: Are you attempting to change it at runtime?

Comment: What OS is being run on both the local machine and remote machine? I've heard of (and seen) file watcher causing issues in Windows 8

Answer (score -1):

Check out for answer at [FileSystemWatcher Fails to access network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960318/filesystemwatcher-fails-to-access-network-drive)

Comment: This should be a comment. And further possibly a close vote as a duplicate.